# Conditions with assigned variables vs inline condition check

Tags: javascript, variables, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

*Can't find a better Title for this question so edit suggestions will be much appreciated.*

I'm wondering if there's a difference between checking condition with assigned variables and inline condition.
for example:

**Option 1:**

```
// inline conditions check
function isSomething(){
    return (1 > 2 || 'a' == 'a' || 2 < 4) || 
           (55 == 1 || (32 > 4 || 'a' == 'a') && 6 > 2) || 
           ('abc' != 'bca' && 3 == 3);
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
// pre assigned variables condition check
function isSomething(){
    const conditionA = 1 > 2 || 'a' == 'a' || 2 < 4; // some complex condition
    const conditionB = 55 == 1 || (32 > 4 || 'a' == 'a') && 6 > 2; // some complex condition
    const conditionC = 'abc' != 'bca' && 3 == 3 // some complex condition

    const result = conditionA || conditionB || conditionC;
    return result;
}
```

It seems that in option 2 it must check all 3 conditions but in option 1 theoretically it can return after the first check if it's `true`.

Obviously option 2 is my choice as it's much more readable, though i was wondering is there a difference in behavior or performance? 
Is there a way to test performance between the two options?

Comment: As for performance tests, if you haven't yet heard of the jsPerf, this could be the best moment to visit the site. There are mutliple alternatives to it, all them online in your browser (e.g. http://jsben.ch/#/7XyeB).

Comment: @WiktorZychla interesting, thanks i didn't know about that. though i get different result sometimes. eg: code block 1 fastest then code block 2 fastest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as checking the performance I would look at [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/).

Also please take a look at `console.time()`, `console.profile()`, and `performance.now()` if you haven't already.

In option 2 you are creating 3 new objects and assigning them to variables, creating object and allocating them in memory, the effect that this will have on performance would tend to be insignificant.

In option 1 if the first value is true the second option will not be evaluated as `||` is a short circuit operator whilst in the second option all three conditions will be evaluated regardless of the result that they return.

If performance is an issue as this method is being used multiple times I would always suggest that the performance test simulates the real world application as much as possible.

Comment: *as you are doing the same conditional checks within both options* This is incorrect. As the OP himself pointed out, the first case will short-circuit, while the second case will not.

Comment: @torazaburo I see in the first case if the first condition is true the other conditions will not be run whilst in the second they will. I will alter the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to combine the benefits of short-circuited evaluation with readability and named variables, then

```
function isSomething(){
  const conditionA = () => 1 > 2 || 'a' == 'a' || 2 < 4;
  const conditionB = () => 55 == 1 || (32 > 4 || 'a' == 'a') && 6 > 2;
  const conditionC = () => 'abc' != 'bca' && 3 == 3;

  const result = conditionA() || conditionB() || conditionC();

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Im not sure this qualifies as the exact answer to my question but this solution is GREAT! haven't thought about it, kinda makes it "lazy" condition check. Thanks a lot.